# How to enable open location on a shorcut in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an installation program for my VB.NET application; after install my application I get the icon on my desktop with the right icon image and open the right application but when I right click on the shortcut *--> Properties* the "**Open location**" button is grayed out.
There's a way to create a regular shortcut with all the buttons enabled?

Second, my application is being installed inside *Program Files(x86)\Microsoft\MyApp*, there's a way to specify a directory outside program files?
I need to write log files and that directory needs that the application runs as Administrator to do that.

I created the installer by adding an Assisted Installation project to my application project.

I tried by using *MyAppSetup.exe* and the *msi* package too with the same results.

Comment: You should be able to specify your company name. The application is usually installed to `Program Files (x86)\<your company name>\<your product name>`. I guess the company is pre-set to `Microsoft` but surely one must be able to change it?

Comment: @VisualVincent I do it on the AssemblyInfo.vb file but still installing it inside Microsoft folder.

Comment: I've never used the so called `Assisted Installation` project... But in the setup project for VS2010 you specify the name in a property.

Comment: @VisualVincent My Visual Studio is in Spanish, so I make a literal translation, maybe I should translate it as Setup Wizard. There's so many path's to create the installer, and so many properties to set that I never end to learn. :/

Comment: Okay :P. The property of the setup wizard is called `CompanyName` in english I believe. Look through the property list in the Property Browser. There you'll find every property related to your installer.